# Unable to receive email on Google domain

Tags: gmail, google-apps

I migrated to a Google App domain recently and I didn't previously have email set up for my domain. So I created an email on my new Google App domain as an administrator. I am able to send emails from this account, but unable to receive emails.

When I try to send an email to the new domain's email, I receive the following error:

```
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the c
```

I strongly believe that I don't need to change any MX Record from my external domain because I don't have this admin account created in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, you need to set up MX records for the domain, [as described in the documentation](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=140034).